# Accessing next asset from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using the UIImagePickerController to choose an image, and display it to the user immediately. However, I want the user to be able to swipe, and the next image from the album appears. The question is, how do I access the next image in the album after the initial user-selected image, programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With UIImagePickerController you just can't.

You need to use the [ALAssets Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for that.

See this example: [Accessing photo library using assets library](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/)

Best,
Christian

Comment: So would I just add all assets to an array so I can access them later? Are assets just pointers? So if I add 400 assets to an array, it wouldn't be a problem? (of course accessing the full resolution image of the asset is a memory intensive task, but as for the assets alone?)

Comment: Ok I've managed to add all assets to an array, but now when the user selects the initial asset, how do I know which index that photo is?

Comment: Are you now using the UIImagePickerController or a custom one? You need to use a custom one. E.g. try ELCImagePickerController which you can find on [github](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)

Comment: Ya I'm using ELCImagePickerController. I'm in the ELCAsset.m. I've already assigned the asset array, now I'm guessing I need to somehow save the index of the selected photo, in the -(void)toggleSelection method in ELCAsset.m-but how?

Comment: You could also modify the method `-(void)selectedAssets:(NSArray*)_assets` inside the `ELCImagePickerController` class so it returns the Assets instead of an array of dictionaries. Then outside you can check on which position the asset is (by gooing through all assets)

Comment: But -(void)selectedAssets is called when the done button is pressed. Only toggleSelection is called when I select an image.

Comment: When toggleSelection is called, I'm running through a loop of my assets array, and finding if at any point my selected asset matches with any of my array assets, but I'm not finding a match. I'm using this line to compare:`if([[appDelegate.arrayOfAssets objectAtIndex:i] isEqual:asset])`

Comment: In general, to get the index, you can use: `[arrayOfAssets indexOfObject:asset]`. And yes, toggleSelection is your friend when you are only interested in one asset.

Comment: Hmm..I'm getting a huge number with that, so I'm guessing it's not finding it. Where should I set my arrayOfAssets? Currently I'm doing it in ELCAssetCell in the setAssets: method like so: `appDelegate.arrayOfAssets=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:_assets]`, but maybe this is not the best place?

Comment: Nm, got it:) I was erroneously comparing ELCAssets with ALAssets